# console.log shows different number (11321144241322243122)

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i try to log this number `11321144241322243122` into the console it always gets converted to this number `11321144241322244000`. This happens in node.js and in the browser console.

Answer (score 2):

`11321144241322243122` is bigger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER).

Instead, convert it to a [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```js
console.log(BigInt("11321144241322243122").toString())

console.log(11321144241322243122)
```